# Highchart networkgraph and area chart conflict

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was trying to put two highcharts charts- networkgraph and area chart in a page. But the area chart not working at all. The console gives the following errors:

```
> TypeError: link is null
```

See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mawiahl/4vkbe63m/10/

If I delete the networkgraph code, the area chart works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add **afterSetOptions** event, it is iterating through all series (included area chart series) when it should only through networkgraph series. Adding simple **if statement** will solve the problem.

```
if (e.options.seriesType === 'networkgraph') {
  ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gw5rucdz